# STS java file editor error hover text setting

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

the latest STS do not show the error description when hover the error code,the error description show on the left core of STS,how to change back show error description when hover to error code?

[image]

sts version

Spring Tool Suite 4

```
Version: 4.6.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 202005250833
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the combined hover implementation: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/470 - fixed in Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse 4.7.0.